# why i am getting the error 'temp1app.CustomUser.user_pe rmissions' or 'auth.User.user_permissions'?

Tags: python, django

Hope you are doing well, i am beginner to the django and python, encountered the error while practicing projects from the github which is the user authentication project. i have posted a code below.                     feel free to ask if you have any questions. i have
posted a question in this StackOverflow website
to find the solution for the issue. please solve
the issue. Thanks a lot for your help.

```
 python manage.py migrate
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File                

 "C:\Users\Dhani\anaconda3\
 envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-     
 packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", l
 ine 187, in check_key
 return self.graph.root_nodes(key[0])[0]
 IndexError: list index out of range

 During handling of the above exception, another      
 exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):

   File "E:\Programming1\GitHub\
 1\temp1\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
 main()
  File "E:\Programming1\GitHub\1\temp1\manage.py",      
 line 18, in main
 execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
   File "C:\Users\Dhani\anaconda3\
 envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-               
 packages\django\
 core\management\__init__.py
 ", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
 utility.execute()
 File "C:\Users\Dhani\anaconda3\
 envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\
 management\__init__.py
 ", line 440, in execute
  self.fetch_command(subcommand).
 run_from_argv(self.argv)
   File "C:\Users\Dhani\anaconda3\envs\
 myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\
 management\base.py", l
 ine 414, in run_from_argvself.execute
 (*args,           **cmd_options)
   File "C:\Users\Dhani\anaconda3\
 envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\
 management\base.py", l
 ine 460, in execute
 output = self.handle(*args, **options)
 ine 250, in build_graph
 self.add_external_dependencies(key, migration)
   File "C:\Users\Dhani\anaconda3\
 envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\
 django\db\migrations\loader.py", l
 ine 214, in add_external_dependencies
     parent = self.check_key(parent, key[0])
   File      


    "C:\Users\Dhani\anaconda3\envs
 \myDjangoEnv\lib\site-               
 packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", l

 ine 194, in check_key
 raise ValueError(
 ValueError: Dependency on app with no migrations: 
 
 temp1app

 temp1/settings.py



from pathlib import Path
import os
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
TEMPLATES_DIR=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-fzd#                        
(ie_srm3k^c+ggwzh5e$gu3j+dp@%!yg92r87r&61d16zr'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'temp1app',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'temp1.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [TEMPLATES_DIR,],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
  },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'temp1.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
 }
   }


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-                        
 validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
{
    'NAME':                                         
'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.
UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
 },
 {
        'NAME':'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.
MinimumLengthValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.
password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.
password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
},
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-    
 field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

#AUTH_USER_MODEL = "temp1app.AbstractUser1"  # new

temp1/urls.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include  # new
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView  # new
from temp1app import URLs
urlpatterns = [
path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
path("", include("temp1app.urls")),  # new
path("accounts", include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),  # new
path("", TemplateView.as_view(template_name="home.html"), name="home"),                  
# new
]

temp1app/admin.py



from pathlib import Path
import os
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
TEMPLATES_DIR=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-fzd#                
  (ie_srm3k^c+ggwzh5e$gu3j+dp@%!yg92r87r&61d16zr'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'temp1app',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'temp1.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [TEMPLATES_DIR,],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
    },
    ]

    WSGI_APPLICATION = 'temp1.wsgi.application'


    # Database
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

    DATABASES = {
    'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-    
 validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
{
    'NAME':     'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.
 UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
},
{
    'NAME':         'django.contrib.auth.
password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.
password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.
password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
},
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-    
field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

#AUTH_USER_MODEL = "temp1app.AbstractUser1"  # new


temp1app/forms.py

from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm

from .models import CustomUser
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
class Meta(UserCreationForm):
    model = CustomUser
    fields = (
        "username",
        "email",
        "age",
    )  # new


class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
class Meta:
    model = CustomUser
    fields = (
        "username",
        "email",
        "age",
    )  # new

temp1app/models.py

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
age = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

temp1app/urls.py

from django.urls import path
from .views import SignUpView

urlpatterns = [
path("signup/", SignUpView.as_view(), name="signup"),
]

temp1app/views.py

from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import CreateView

from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm


class SignUpView(CreateView):
form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
success_url = reverse_lazy("login")
template_name = "registration/signup.html"


templates/home.html

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
  <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
<h1>Django</h1>


  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <a href="{% url 'logout' %}">logout</a>
  {% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'login' %}">login</a>
    <a href="{% url 'signup' %}">signup</a>
  {% endif %}

{% block content %}

{% endblock}
  </body>
</html>

templates/registration/signin.html

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
  <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
  {% extends 'home.html' %}

  {% block content %}
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}

      <input type="submit" value="signin">
  </form>
  {% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>

templates/registration/signup.html

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
  </head>
<body>
{% extends 'home.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}

      <input type="submit" value="signup">
  </form>
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add the `CustomUser` model, please

Answer (score 0):

You should add `AUTH_USER_MODEL = "temp1app.CustomUser"` to your settings.

Comment: After this action . I am getting error that is Dependency on app no migrations: temp1app(this is app name)

Comment: Do you get anything if you run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`? If not, can you send the entire error log?

Comment: error message length is longer than the comment box size so I have added the error message in the question. please have a look. thank you

Comment: What's the output when you run `python manage.py makemigrations`?